# Proxy service run through scheduled task in wso2 esb is giving error "Unexpected error sending message back"

Tags: soap, wso2, esb

We have created a proxy service in wso2 esb using esb poject in eclipse. This proxy service is invoking 2 web services, first one query data from legacy system and the other one creates sale order in oracle fusion.

This proxy service when run from soap ui executes successfully and creates sale order with no error. While when when run from scheduled task, it runs and creates order but gives error "Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}" in wso2carbon.log file.

The xml for scheduled task is as follows

```
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
        group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="testtask2">
        <trigger count="1" interval="60"/>
        <property name="proxyName" value="EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="soapAction" value="operation" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="injectTo" value="proxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="to"
            value="http://10.1.6.176:8280/services/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS.EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPSHttpSoap11Endpoint" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:esl="esl" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <esl:operation/>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </property>
    </task>
```

The complete error log is as follows

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-23 06:19:17,471] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Connection:keep-alive,Content-Language:en,Content-Length:0,Content-Type:,Date:Thu, 23 Feb 2017 06:19:17 GMT,Server:Oracle-Application-Server-11g,Set-Cookie:<oracle fusion url>; httponly; secure; path=/,X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID:005IImNkZMq3z005RzH7id0001U70002LZ,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:432)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:222)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.RespondMediator.mediate(RespondMediator.java:35)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:766)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>` inside your `EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS` proxy.

And I think you can remove `to` property since the message is sent to proxy given in `proxyName` property.

Comment: adding OUT_ONLY property did not work.. can u plz specify how to add it?

Comment: after adding my proxy is like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
         <call/>
         <datamapper/>
         <header/>
         <call/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>

Comment: remove `respond` and put OUT_ONLY just before 2nd call.